# optimization of multivariate function in r

Tags: r

This question is pretty simple but I could not find a solution in the internet. Please bear my naivete!

I am a day trader and using R to get the most profitable 4 stocks for the next day. w,x,y,z are the weights of the stocks, and r1,r2,r3,r4 are the returns of the stocks.

The total return of the 4 stocks is:

T = w*r1 + x*r2 + y*r3 + z*r4

How do I maximize T in R, given w+x+y+z = 1? How do I get the values of w,x,y,z for the max T? Can I use `optim`?  I could not find the use of `optim` for multivariate functions, specifically applicable to my problem in the Internet.

Very many thanks for your time and effort...

Comment: Check the base `?constrOptim` function.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand but shouldn't you simply set the weight of the stock with highest return to 1 (and all others to 0)?

Comment: If you optimize based on profits only (not taking into account variability, risk spreading, etc.), then your maximization function is pretty simple: find the max of r1, ... , r4 and put all weight there. Again, I'm not saying its a good idea, rather, you need to amend your optimization function.

Comment: I think the above answers are right...but I want to go for 4 stocks to minimize risk...so I cannot put all weight in stock....how about this?

Comment: That means you have to create some kind of constraints, for example: w,x,y,z <= 0.4; w,x,y,z > 0; w+y < 0.5; ... (randomly made up)